# How can i parse a Resource Description Framework Schema file?

Tags: parsing, rdfs

I would like to parse a Resource Description Framework Schema file in
order to output the subClasses of a class or the subProperties of it.

Is there any open source tool available online?
Or shall i create a DOM parser in order to parse the Resource Description Framework Schema file?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of free software/open source RDF systems available.  If you start at http://www.w3.org/RDF/ you can find them.  It primarily depends on what programming language you use.  There are super solid solutions in all the major languages.